# Error coming in Ubuntu terminal : "Command line option 'n' [from -installed] is not understood in combination with the other options."

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I was trying to list all installed packages. I ran this command:

> $ sudo apt list all

Then it says "Listing done" but it does not output anything else. I think this command is wrong.
Then I ran the following command :

> $ sudo apt list -installed

I got this error :

> Command line option 'n' [from -installed] is not understood in combination with the other options.

I also tried "sudo apt-get list -installed". But this is showing the same error.

I am new to Ubuntu and terminal scripting. Did I break something in my system because of wrong command. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line should be:

```
apt list --installed
```

The `-intalled` option doesn't exist that's why you have recived `command.. is not understood` error. It doesn't break anything.

Comment: @MilanOinam You are welcome, don't forget to accept my answer, please.